# Splitting up an array formed by an api in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on some stat tracking code for a game (yes, it's runescape. sue me).

I want to pull information from the high scores using an api which produces an array looking like this (captured using print_r)

```
Array
(
    [getHiscore] => Array
        (
            [overall] => Array
                (
                    [rank] => 61995
                    [lvl] => 2273
                    [totalxp] => 193310588
                )

            [attack] => Array
                (
                    [rank] => 93406
                    [lvl] => 97
                    [totalxp] => 11747494
                )
```

...and so on.
My question is how can i take what this api gives me and place it into a database table; I want to get an array such as this for a particular user and update their stats with it. 
Would i use explode? It seems like the right idea to me but how would i actually use it to split the separate numbers and words?

My database is not totally realised yet, however each record will include a user name and then the level and total xp in each of 27 "skills". This almost certainly not best practice for database design but i'm as novice as they come so it's the best i can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to explode. It's an array and therefore it's already exploded. You need to iterate through it to build meaningful queries.

I'm not familiar with runescape so I don't know if your example is showing just the relevant fields of you need to discard some part. If it's the former, then you should try something like

```
$query="insert into stats_table (description, rank, lvl, totalexp) values (:description, :rank, :lvl, :totalext);";
$Statement = $DBConn->prepare($query);

foreach($fullArray as $description=>$subArray) {
    $Statement->bindValue(':description',$description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    foreach($subArray as $key=>$value) {
        $Statement->bindValue($key,$value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
    $Statement->execute();
}
```

That will insert two rows containing

```
overall    61995    2273    193310588
attack    93406    97    11747494
```

PD: $DBConn is a [PDO connection instance](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) to whatever DB engine you're using.

Comment: This would probably work fine if i had one table for each individual user but my instincts are telling me that i shouldn't do that. Correct me if i'm wrong but shouldn't  a database only use a fairly small number of tables? This might be different as each user/record would have maybe 40 bits of data associated with it.

Comment: In the simplest case, just one table will do, and each player's record should have a unique identifier. Your example showed no ID field to identify one particular player but that id should go in the query too.

Comment: My DB does have a unique ID, this data is just pulled from the game's website so it's not setup for a database yet. If i were to use one table surly i would need one row for each user, in which case would i be able to switch it so that code inserts into one row? (you're being very helpful, sorry for having no idea what i'm doing).

Comment: Yeah, you just need to add player_id or something into the query, but you still need to figure out how to get player id from runescape API. To make your own life easier, you should use the same id in your DB.

Comment: @JonathanCrouch With regards to number of tables, that's case by case, but it's often time better to have more tables than columns, in fact it's even more useful. What can slow you down is the number of joins you have to perform to get the data you want, so it really depends on how you design your database, not how many tables you have.

Answer (score 0):

Just pull the arrays out with a foreach loop and write some sql to insert the data. I don't know anything about your DB so if you want help there update your question please.

Simplest way to do this:

```
foreach($highscores as $highScoreType => $highScoreValues){
    $rank = $highScoreValues['rank'];
    $lvl = $highScoreValues['lvl'];
    $totalXp = $highScoreValues['totalxp'];

    //then it's up to you to put it into a table somehow.
}
```

$highScoreType will contain the values 'overall','attack',etc

This format of the foreach loop is extremely handy when iterating over an associative array (hash map/hash table, which is actually what all PHP arrays are underneath) will allow you to not only grab the value of the current pointed to entry, but also the key for that entry.

So, assume we have a single entry hashmap with key 'foo' and value 'bar'. If I want to show 'bar' I would simple

```
echo $map['foo'];//will output 'bar'
```

and if I put this into the above type of foreach loop

```
foreach($map as $fooKey => $barValue) {
    echo $fooKey;//outputs 'foo'
    echo $barValue;//outputs 'bar'
}
```

Comment: If that loops through each bit of the array for those three variables, how would i identify the skill it was referring to?

Comment: foreach loops of this format give you not only the value, but the key as well, and since yours keys are the skill itself, $highScoreType will contain the 'skill'

Comment: So assuming i have $highscoretype populated after the foreach gets $total xp do i have to split it up for the sql? If i am correct in thinking that once it gets the totalxp and sees no other code it'll just increment and overwrite highscoretype with the next part of the array. Could i just use this code to update the database with each pass?  mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Users SET Rank=$rank, TotalLevel = $lvl, TotalXp = $totalXp'
 WHERE UserName='$name'");

Comment: well, that's just going to keep overwriting the same row with the "type" as you put it. Where are you actually using the $highScoreType?

Comment: Don't i have to use it inside the foreach? I'm a little lost here.

Comment: Yes, both $highScoreType and $highScoreValues are available inside the foreach. I'll update hte answer with an explanation

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this is all stored in the variable `$ary`:

```
$ary['getHiscore']['overall']['rank'] = 61995;
$ary['getHiscore']['overall']['lvl'] = 2273;
$ary['getHiscore']['overall']['totalxp'] = 193310588;

$ary['getHiscore']['attack']['rank'] = 93406;
$ary['getHiscore']['attack']['lvl'] = 97;
$ary['getHiscore']['attack']['totalxp'] = 11747494;
```

So, to get those values, it's:

```
$attackLevel = $ary['getHiscore']['attack']['lvl'];
```

If you

```
echo $attackLevel;
```

it would be `97`.